# How to get time from DateTime column in SQL Server database to DataGridView column?

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, datagridview

This is a part of my code where I retrieve all columns from my `IncomingLog` table from my database to the DGV in my Winform application. I have already fixed the `Date` column, but I can't fix the `Time` column of my DataGridView (this: "HH:mm:ss tt" doesn't work, still displays the time (7:26 AM, which is correct) AND date (1/1/1900, which is not correct)).

[image]

Can someone help me? Thanks!

```
DataTable dt;

_db.conn();
_db.cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM IncomingLog";

dt = _db.executeDT();

incomLogTable.DataSource = dt;

incomLogTable.Columns[2].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "MM/dd/yyyy";
incomLogTable.Columns[4].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "HH:mm:ss tt";
```

Comment: What's wrong with it? Does the hour not display correctly? If so, try hh:mm:ss tt. Also, was it intentional to have single quotes around your code? It gets rid of any formatting SA does to the block.

Comment: The hour doesn't display correctly. It still shows mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm AM/PM. One of my Time rows has this: 1/1/1900 7:25 AM. The time tho is correct.

Comment: The single quotes around my code was included when I asked this. Lol, it's not really in my code. UPDATE: I tried the hh:mm:ss tt, still the same.

Comment: HH is for 24 hour format. use hh along with tt. "HH:mm:ss" or "hh:mm:ss tt"

Comment: Can you provide the data types for the SQL table columns you are querying and some sample rows? You may want to do the formatting in the SQL query instead of the c#.

Comment: @AndrewO'Brien `Date_Received` and `Time_Received` columns are both DateTime. Can you show me how to do the formatting in the query? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since both columns are datetime, it looks like the time is defaulting to date 0 (01/01/1990) when the time is generated. As a side note, ideally date and time would be one column if they are both stored as timestamps.

The first option is to convert the datetime into a string and scrape the string for the value you want. You can read on formatting timestamps in SQL Server [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp). If you can get the format you want from this then it is the easier of the 2. The below will return 7:26AM as a string.

```
declare @date datetime = '1990-01-01 07:26:00'

select substring(convert(nvarchar(max),@date,0),12,20)
```

The other option is to break the datetime into dateparts and then put them together in whatever format you want. The below will return 7:26 AM.

```
declare @date datetime = '1990-01-01 07:26:00'

select
    cast(datepart(hour,@date) as varchar(2)) --Assign hour
    + ':' --Add asterisk
    + cast(datepart(minute,@date) as varchar(2)) --Assign minute
    + ' ' --Add space before AM/PM
    + case when datepart(hour,@date) > 12 then 'PM' else 'AM' end --Determine AM vs PM and add
```